# What's with all the random tweets?

Tags: twitter

OK, so I just started using twitter and I'm confused. I have no interest in Justin Beiber, nor does anyone else I follow on Twitter. So why does my home page show Justin Beiber tweets?  Or more specifically, why do I see so many tweets from people I'm *not* following, and none from the people I am following?  And the majority of the random tweets are from subjects I'm not even interested in.

Comment: Do you follow anyone? Do you see "Retweeted by ..." on any of the tweets?

Comment: I follow some people, but the people that retweet what I'm seeing aren't people I follow.  It was like this right from when I first signed up.

Comment: What's an example tweet? Maybe it was sponsored, maybe it's part of another experiment.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I could possibly be due to the retweets by the people you are following, retweets also show in the timeline.

Comment: Are you logged in under the correct account?

Answer (score 2):

You may be seeing this as a result of an experiment in user engagement and retention by Twitter, where you see favourited tweets show up as if they were normal tweets and retweets.

> #### [Twitter's Retweet Experiment Will Make You Rethink Your Favorites](http://readwrite.com/2014/08/18/twitter-experiment-retweet-favorites-timeline)
>
> In its latest effort to engage newbies, Twitter is sharing "favorite" tweets on some accounts as if they are re-tweets.

This should explain why you're seeing tweets from accounts that seemingly have no relation to those you follow since they didn't explicitly retweet them.

You could also be seeing [Promoted Tweets](https://business.twitter.com/products/promoted-tweets), but these will usually be marked as such and show a button where you can "dismiss" it from your timeline. With promoted tweets you can be targeted "against" one of your interests.

For example, if you follow the [@BlackFishMovie](https://twitter.com/BlackFishMovie) you may see sponsored tweets coming from [@SeaWorld](https://twitter.com/seaworld) and such actions are only limited to those who can pay.